# Different results with weighted t test between R and Python

Tags: python, r, t-test

I'm running a weighted t test in Python and am seeing different results.  It appears that the issue is the degree of freedom calculation.  Would like to understand why I'm seeing different outputs.

Here is some sample code.

In R:

```
library(weights)
x <- c(373,398,245,272,238,241,134,410,158,125,198,252,577,272,208,260)
y <- c(411,471,320,364,311,390,163,424,228,144,246,371,680,384,279,303)

weightsa = c(rep(1,8), rep(2,8))
weightsb = c(rep(2,8), rep(1,8))

wtd.t.test(x = x,
           y = y,
           weight = weightsa,
           weighty = weightsb, samedata=F)

$test [1] "Two Sample Weighted T-Test (Welch)"

$coefficients
    t.value          df     p.value 
-1.88907197 29.93637837  0.06860382 

$additional Difference     Mean.x     Mean.y   Std. Err   -80.50000 
267.12500  347.62500   42.61352
```

In Python:

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.stats.weightstats import ttest_ind
x = np.asarray([373,398,245,272,238,241,134,410,158,125,198,252,577,272,208,260])
y = np.asarray([411,471,320,364,311,390,163,424,228,144,246,371,680,384,279,303])

weightsa = [1] * 8 + [2] * 8
weightsb = [2] * 8 + [1] * 8

ttest_ind(x, y, usevar='unequal', weights=(weightsa, weightsb))

(-2.3391969704691085, 0.023733058922455107, 45.90244683439944)
```

P value is .06 in R, .02 in Python.
The R source code uses the Satterthwaite formula for degrees of freedom:

```
df <- (((vx/n) + (vy/n2))^2)/((((vx/n)^2)/(n - 1)) + 
      ((vy/n2)^2/(n2 - 1)))
```

The Python function source code also purports to use this formula:

```
def dof_satt(self):
        '''degrees of freedom of Satterthwaite for unequal variance
        '''
        d1 = self.d1
        d2 = self.d2
        #this follows blindly the SPSS manual
        #except I use  ``_var`` which has ddof=0
        sem1 = d1._var / (d1.nobs-1)
        sem2 = d2._var / (d2.nobs-1)
        semsum = sem1 + sem2
        z1 = (sem1 / semsum)**2 / (d1.nobs - 1)
        z2 = (sem2 / semsum)**2 / (d2.nobs - 1)
        dof = 1. / (z1 + z2)
        return dof
```

The numerator here looks the same but the denominator appears quite different.

Comment: The denominator there is in fact the same, which you can confirm with some (tedious) algebraic manipulation

Comment: So what makes the output different then?

Comment: Not sure, but I know it's not the degrees of freedom. Will try to investigate further tomorrow if no answer by then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you had here is that `weights::wtd.t.test()` has a (to me, strange) default argument `mean1 = TRUE`, which governs "whether the weights should be forced to have an average value of 1" (from `help("wtd.t.test")`).

If we use `mean1 = FALSE`, we get the same behavior as `ttest_ind()`:

```
wtd.t.test(x = x,
           y = y,
           weight = weightsa,
           weighty = weightsb,
           samedata = FALSE,
           mean1 = FALSE)

$test
[1] "Two Sample Weighted T-Test (Welch)"

$coefficients
    t.value          df     p.value 
-2.33919697 45.90244683  0.02373306 

$additional
Difference     Mean.x     Mean.y   Std. Err 
 -80.50000  267.12500  347.62500   34.41352
```